# (Angular) How can I get the fullcalendar's current view date information?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

In HTML code...

```
<full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [plugins]="calendarPlugins" #calendar></fullcalendar>
```

then, How can I get the date info from #calendar element?..
I tried to find the fullcalendar's documentation,
There wasn't enough information for Angular.
(Implementation in HTML ... just a property for Month ...)

fullcalendar/month : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/month 
fullcalendar/getDate() : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/getDate

What I want is to create an element in HTML, and in Typescript, create a variable containing the month information for that calendar element. (without using JQuery)
I would like to seek advice on this.

Comment: Those links are wrong - you seem to be using the version 1 documentation, but the fullCalendar Angular plugin is based on the current fullCalendar version 4 - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc for documentation of the current version.

Comment: If you want to get the info about the current view, at the moment you need it you can read from the [view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) property which will contain the start and end dates of the full date range being displayed, or you can use [getDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getDate) to get a single "current" date. (To do either of these things with the fullCalendar Angular plugin you need to first get access to the API - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular explains how to do this in the section "accessing FullCalendar’s API"). Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the date of the current calendar in this way.

```
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; 

private calendarApi

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
  let currentDate = this.calendarApi.view.currentStart;

  console.log(currentDate); // result: current calendar start date
}
```